# Spring Integration Multipart form Uploads route with JSON response not working

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a spring integration route in xml which will make a web service call (multipart/formdata) *and need to return the response in JSON format*. The problem is I don't find any good sample SI route that do a multipart request with response. Any help is really appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">

<bean id="byteArrayHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
</bean>

<bean id="formHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter">
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

<bean id="headerMapper"
    class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
    <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
    <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
</bean>


<int:channel id="http.request.submit.withfiles" />
<int:channel id="http.response.submit.withfiles" />

<int:channel id="http.router.route1.process.submit.withfiles" />
<int:channel id="http.router.route2.process.submit.withfiles" />

<int-http:inbound-gateway id="http.gateway.inbound.submit.withfiles"
    supported-methods="POST" header-mapper="headerMapper" 
    request-channel="http.request.submit.withfiles"
    reply-channel="http.response.submit.withfiles" path="/v1.0/file">
    <int-http:request-mapping consumes="multipart/form-data"
        produces="application/json" />
    <int-http:header name="routingCode" expression="headers['routingCode']" />

</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:header-value-router input-channel="http.request.submit.withfiles"
    header-name="routingCode" default-output-channel="http.router.route2.process.submit.withfiles">
    <int:mapping value="AB"
        channel="http.router.route1.process.submit.withfiles" />
    <int:mapping value="AC"
        channel="http.router.route2.process.submit.withfiles" />
    <int:mapping value="AD"
        channel="http.router.route2.process.submit.withfiles" />
    <int:mapping value="AE"
        channel="http.router.route2.process.submit.withfiles" />
    <int:mapping value="AF"
        channel="http.router.route2.process.submit.withfiles" />
</int:header-value-router>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
    id="http.gateway.outbound.route1.submit.withfiles" header-mapper="headerMapper"
    request-channel="http.router.route1.process.submit.withfiles"
    reply-channel="http.response.submit.withfiles"
    url="http://localhost:8080/myapplication1/file"
    http-method-expression="headers.http_requestMethod"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8" 
    reply-timeout="50000" />

<int-http:outbound-gateway
    id="http.gateway.outbound.route2.submit.withfiles" header-mapper="headerMapper"
    request-channel="http.router.route2.process.submit.withfiles"
    reply-channel="http.response.submit.withfiles" 
    url="http://localhost:8081/myapplication2/file"
    http-method="POST" charset="UTF-8" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    reply-timeout="50000">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Error Message:

```
02-Sep-2015 13:36:07.300 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-13] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [springServlet] in context with path [/my-switcher] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://localhost:8081/myapplication2/file]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.springframework.integration.http.multipart.UploadedMultipartFile["inputStream"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.springframework.integration.http.multipart.UploadedMultipartFile["inputStream"])] with root cause
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.springframework.integration.http.multipart.UploadedMultipartFile["inputStream"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2240)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writePart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:331)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeParts(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:311)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeMultipart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:301)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:240)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:774)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:545)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:466)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:422)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:286)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:188)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:286)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:331)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:302)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.actualDoHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:492)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.doHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:389)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

More Details:

The actual webservice (http://localhost:8081/myapplication2/file) do a multipart form upload and returns a json message back to the calling application. So what I am expecting from this SI route  is the http-outbound gateway will call the above webservice and do a postupload and returns a json response .

Also I am passing the request via postman like this.
[image]

Comment: Questions that simply say "(x) is not working" generally don't get much attention here. You need to explain what you've tried and exactly what you mean by "not working", by adding logs, stack traces etc. as evidence.
 See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edited with error Message and details

Comment: For some reason, the outbound `RestTemplate` is trying to convert the `UploadedMultipartFile` to JSON (which won't work).
I need to do some experimentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gary.

As of now I resolved this issue by replacing the 'http outbound gate way' with 'service activator' and invoke the webservice via REST Template inside the class which is referred in the service activator.

```
<int:service-activator id="serviceactivator"        
    input-channel="http.router.process.submit.withfiles" 
    output-channel="http.response.submit.withfiles"     
    ref="multipartReceiver" method="receive"
    requires-reply="true" >
</int:service-activator>
```

Answer (score 2):

Proxying a `multipart/form-data` request like this is not currently supported.

The problem is that Spring MVC has converted the raw form data to a `MultipartHttpInputMessage`; which is further converted by the inbound gateway to a `MultiValueMap`, where the file part(s) is(are) `UploadedMultipartFile` instances.

The outbound gateway does not know how to process this object; there's not a converter for it.

You could try adding a transformer, to convert the `UploadedMultiPartFile` element(s) in the payload to `Resource`(s), or write a custom `MessageConverter` and inject it into the outbound gateway.

We are seeing more and more of these HTTP "proxy" scenarios, so please open a 'new feature' [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Even better, consider [contributing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) a solution!

**EDIT:**

Here is another work around - and it is more efficient. Effectively we want to disable multi-part decoding in the inbound gateway, and pass the multi-part request unchanged to the outbound.

Here's how to do it...

**Remove the multipart resolver bean**

**Add a custom "pass-thru" multi-part converter to the inbound gateway...**

```
public class PassThroughMultiPartConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<byte[]> {

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        if (!(byte[].class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (mediaType != null) {
            return MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.includes(mediaType)
                    || MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.includes(mediaType);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        return Collections.singletonList(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] read(Class<? extends byte[]> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputMessage.getBody(), baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] t, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway 
    ...
                                  request-payload-type="byte[]"
                                  message-converters="converter"
                                  merge-with-default-converters="false" />

<bean id="converter" class="foo.PassThroughMultiPartConverter" />
```

Comment: Support will be added in the [upcoming 4.2 release](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3818).