# Error in processing a Multipart file message using Spring Cloud Data Flow HttpSource and FileSink

Tags: multipartform-data, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have created following simple stream in spring cloud data flow local
httpsource | filesink using default properties. I am sending an XML file to httpsource via POST. I am using POSTMAN and doing following settings
POST http://144.114.172.3:47783
Body -> form-data
Key File of type File and value is chosen XML file
contentType : multipart/form-data
In file sink I am getting following error

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException:
>   Unable to deserialize [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap]
>   using the contentType
>   [application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap]
>   Unable to find class:
>   org.springframework.integration.http.multipart.UploadedMultipartFile;
>   nested exception is com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to
>   find class:
>   org.springframework.integration.http.multipart.UploadedMultipartFile
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.deserializePayload(AbstractBinder.java:265)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.deserializePayload(AbstractBinder.java:234)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.deserializePayloadIfNecessary(AbstractBinder.java:213)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.deserializePayloadIfNecessary(AbstractBinder.java:207)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$ReceivingHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:291)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]    ... 34
>   common frames omitted Caused by:
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class:
>   org.springframework.integration.http.multipart.UploadedMultipartFile
>     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:156)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:133)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:781)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:161)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
>   org.springframework.integration.codec.kryo.PojoCodec.doDecode(PojoCodec.java:97)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.codec.kryo.AbstractKryoCodec$3.execute(AbstractKryoCodec.java:96)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:61)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
>   org.springframework.integration.codec.kryo.AbstractKryoCodec.decode(AbstractKryoCodec.java:93)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.codec.kryo.AbstractKryoCodec.decode(AbstractKryoCodec.java:79)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.deserializePayload(AbstractBinder.java:260)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.1.RELEASE]  ... 40
>   common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.integration.http.multipart.UploadedMultipartFile
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
>   ~[filesink-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:154)
>   ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar!/:na]     ... 55 common frames omitted

Here is how message from source to sink looks like

> (Body:'[B@24fcbde5(byte[4784])' MessageProperties
>   [headers={content-length=4858, http_requestMethod=POST,
>   host=144.114.172.3:47783, http_requestUrl=http://144.114.172.3:47783/,
>   connection=keep-alive, cache-control=no-cache,
>   contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap,
>   accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, accept=*/*,
>   originalContentType=multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------512524439543335584289928;charset=UTF-8,
>   user-agent=PostmanRuntime/6.1.6}, timestamp=null, messageId=null,
>   userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null,
>   type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null,
>   contentType=application/x-java-object;type=org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap,
>   contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null,
>   receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0,
>   redelivered=false, receivedExchange=test.idea-httpsource,
>   receivedRoutingKey=test.idea-httpsource, receivedDelay=null,
>   deliveryTag=6, messageCount=0,
>   consumerTag=amq.ctag-IVuCqSrqPF11rqIS4lPoUg,
>   consumerQueue=test.httpsource.test])

What could be going wrong?

Comment: So I added spring-integration-http as dependecy in POM and notw getting following error : Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: failed to write Message payload to file; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported Message payload type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap]

Answer (score 2):

This is due contentType negotiation. When you set the contentType to multipart, the httpsource is probably converting it to `LinkedMultiValueMap`, and then because the default for java types is to use Kryo serialization, what is sent over the wire is actually a serialized payload of that class. On the receiving side you probably can't deserialize it back.

[Update]

The issue is indeed due content type conversion. Take a look at this section on the spring cloud stream docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#contenttypemanagement

If you send your data as text/plain instead of using POSTMAN. The dataflow shell as a nice utility command : `http post` that can send data to an app: `http post http://localhost:9000 --file logback-spring.xml`, with this you will avoid type conversion.

Also please note that you would need to set the directory and file names of the file sink. A simple example would be: `--file.directory=/tmp/ --file.name-expression='file.'+headers.id` This will create a new file on your /tmp/ dir named 'file.', from this example you could build better expressions to suit your needs

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that if I use Binary option in postman I am able to send the file , same way http post will do which maps to string. I was going through this question,  and hoping to implement something like what is suggested there -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340610/spring-integration-multipart-form-uploads-route-with-json-response-not-working ... This is just a test scenario I was doing , In real application both sftp filesource and http stream pass a message to a processor which does further processing.

Comment: Well, after some team discussion we would like to ask you to raise an issue on the matter https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/http and we will implement something out-of-the-box.

Comment: Issue created: https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/http/issues/10. I have another one created for file as well, I'll see if I can submit a PR for both this weekend